# ?Length=16 being appended to my URL in my MVC3 application

Tags: asp.net, view, controller, asp.net-mvc-3

Here's the controller code:

```
public ActionResult AddFriend(string username)
{
    //Todo: Add functionality to add a friend. 

    //Then redirect to that same profile.
    return RedirectToAction("Detail", "Profile", username);
}
```

Contents of `username` is `stapia.gutierrez`, not 16 or anything like that.

When I visit the link:

```
http://localhost:9198/profile/friend/add/stapia.gutierrez
```

The above action is called because I create a route in Global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute("AddFriend", // Route name 
            "Profile/Friend/Add/{username}", // URL with parameters 
            new { controller = "Profile", action = "AddFriend" } // Parameter defaults 
);
```

After clicking the URL is shown as:

```
http://localhost:9198/Profile/stapia.gutierrez?Length=16
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the route values like so:

```
return RedirectToAction("Detail", "Profile", new { username="value" });
```

Comment: Well thank you! :) That fixed it. I didn't know you have to pass around anonymous types instead of plain strings as the action signature requests. Good to know for the future. Thanks again.

Comment: @jdavies - Why? Where is `length=16` coming from?